# SeqAn C++ library : different rID values for bam vs. sam with identical data, bam results in assertion failure due to length of namestore

Tags: c++, bioinformatics, sequencing, seqan, bam

I'm using seqan 1.4.1 to read sam/bam files. I have a sam and bam file from the same data (an alignment to rn5 refseq genes). Oddly enough I didn't get this error when I aligned to ensembl genes.

I am reading the sam/bam files BamStream, but the same error occurs if I drop down to the lower-level Stream approach.

I print length(bamStreamIn._nameStore) and each record.rID as it's read in. Here's my output when I use the bam file version of the data:

```
namestore size 42252
record.rID : 10364
record.rID : 41714
record.rID : 20136
record.rID : 5043
..c/Users/XXXX/shared/seqan-library-1.4.1/include/seqan/bam_io/read_bam.h:208 Assertion failed : static_cast<__uint64>(record.rID) < length(nameStore(context)) was: 43257 >= 42252
```

Here's the output when I use the sam file:

```
namestore size 42252
record.rID : 10318
record.rID : 41436
record.rID : 20031
record.rID : 5009
record.rID : 13876
record.rID : 12206
...
(output continues successfully until the end of the file)
```

Interestingly the namestore size is the same, but the rIDs are different. Any idea why the rIDs are different and what's causing the assertion error?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version?  the current code in gitHub has that line that threw the assertion error at line 250 not line 208.

Comment: it's the most recent stable version - 1.4.1. Is the latest development version likely to fix this issue? Has the .bam reading implementation changed much since the last stable version?

Comment: I don't know.  I've actually never used SeqAn myself.  However, the release notes on their webpage say 1.4.1 was released in July 2013.  there have been at least 4 bug fixing commits to the read_bam.h file since then.  I would recommend pulling the latest version from github and if that still throws an error submit a bug report.

Comment: good call. it's fixed in the trunk, but not the stable release.